# What is Adobe Media Server IP multicast?

Tags: adobe, flash-media-server

I want to know how can it benefit my application if I have the version that have IP multicast. Please explain to me in simple terms. Thanks

Comment: Adobe's docs and examples for this are literally the first hit in google for your question

Comment: hello, i found the answer in the faq of adobe media server. i want to ask how flash player 10.1 do not need a server connection to receive the stream? then how will it receive the data if it is not connected to any server? does that mean that ip multicast is only useful for internal networks?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Media Server supports IP multicast streaming and recording for live video to Flash Player 10.1 or later. Multicast is a highly optimized method to deliver high-quality video to a very large audience with virtually no impact on the server as demand increases.

Adobe Media Server can generate a multicast broadcast from any live RTMP stream or a linear stream from a server-side playlist. Flash Player 10.1 and later clients do not need a server connection to receive the stream. Multicast is very useful for large-scale broadcasts within enterprise networks.

Video players developed with OSMF will have full support for IP multicast.

Source-specific multicast (SSM) lets you generate and consume both SSM and any-source multicast (ASM), enabling stream replication, server-side recording, or rebroadcast over separate multicast channels or RTMFP groups. SSM support reduces the demand on the network resources while also improving the security of the streams.